is there a one-pass spark GraphX algo to separate a graph into small groups
Suppose I have following graph:




Node_id
Node_out_degree




1
1


2
2


3
1


4
4


5
0


6
1


7
2


8
1


9
0



Choose the node whose out degree is the biggest, it's node 4 and find its outgoing nodes 1, 3, 6, then group them as {4, 1, 3, 6}, remove all these nodes and related edges from the graph,
can get below graph:

compute the outdegree,



Node_id
Node_out_degree




2
2


5
0


7
1


8
1


9
0



node 2 have max out degree, found group {2, 5, 7}
repeat the step, found last group {8, 9}
So the final result is as below:
{{4, 1, 3, 6}, {2, 7, 5}, {8,9}}
I have do following test, it do can get the result:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import sys
import os

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .master("local[4]")
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'graphframes:graphframes:0.8.3-spark3.5-s_2.12')
    .getOrCreate()
)



import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *


ids = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([ (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9) ]).map(lambda item : Row(item))
schema =  StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType(), False)])

vertices = spark.createDataFrame(ids, schema)
import graphframes as gf

edges = spark.createDataFrame([
  (1, 2, "similar"),
  (2, 3, "similar"),
  (3, 1, "similar"),
  (4, 3, "similar"),
  (4, 1, "similar"),
  (4, 6, "similar"),
  (6, 4, "similar"),
  (2, 5, "similar"),
  (2, 7, "similar"),
  (7, 2, "similar"),
  (8, 9, "similar")
], ["src", "dst", "relationship"])


g = gf.GraphFrame(vertices, edges)

out_degree_df = g.outDegrees
i  = 0
prev_graph = g
while out_degree_df.isEmpty() == False:
    max_out_degree_ptn=out_degree_df.agg(F.max_by("id", "outDegree")).head()[0]
    dst_column=prev_graph.edges.filter("src = %d" % max_out_degree_ptn).select("dst")
    dst_list=[row[0] for row in dst_column.collect()]
    dst_list.insert(0, max_out_degree_ptn)
    remove_id_list=dst_list
    print("group %d:  %s"%(i, remove_id_list))
    condition=(prev_graph.vertices.id.isin(remove_id_list) == False)
    cur_graph=prev_graph.filterVertices(condition)
    out_degree_df=cur_graph.outDegrees
    prev_graph=cur_graph
    i = i + 1



the output is :
group 0:  [4, 3, 1, 6]
group 1:  [2, 5, 7]
group 2:  [8, 9]

Current this method is doable but it need many iterations and have poor performances when the graph is large, like millions of nodes.
Is there any efficient algo to do this in one-pass or few iterations?

You can't parallelize because your algorithm is inherently iterative. As a optimization, you can use connected components to find disjoint subgraphs. But that's about it.

@user238607 yes, seems cannot parallelize this algo, I am wondering if there is similar algo like label propagation can speed it.
